# IndexedDB: Query index where value "contains"

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I think the answer is "you can't do it that way", but I wanted to be sure. Let's say I have an object:

```
var person = {
    name: 'Joe',
    phoneNumbers: [ '5555554455', '4445554455' ]
};
```

I want to create an index on phoneNumbers:

```
objectStore.createIndex('phoneNumberIndex', 'phoneNumbers');
```

Later I want to query for persons with a particular phoneNumber:

```
index.get('4445554455').onsuccess = function(event) {
    // Anything?
};
```

Will that produce a result? If not, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the `{multientry: true}` parameter of createIndex for that.

Comment: sorry, I meant: I think you can use the `{multientry: true}` paramter of createIndex for that.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
objectStore.createIndex("phoneNumberIndex", "phoneNumber", { multiEntry: true });
objectStore.index("phoneNumberIndex").get("4445554455").onsuccess = function(e) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.result));
}
```